# Label having extra space from top bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have created a custom cell below like this.
[image]

Issue is when I first launch then it takes height (which is from top and bottom).But when scroll up & down then extra height is removed. I am not able to understand why this issue is happening.

Top label has line number as fixed.
Second label has line number as 0.
[image]

**Code for controller**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 15
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell:SampleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SampleCell") as! SampleCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.labelDescription.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.f Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.f Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.f Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like "
        
    } else {
        cell.labelDescription.text = "skdfjksj gkfjg"
    }
    tableView.sizeToFit()
    return cell
}
```

Constraint for UIImage

[image]

Constraint for Top UILabel
[image]

Constraints for bottom UILabel
[image]

Comment: Show us contraints of all these components.

Comment: Give each of your label a different and visible background colour, it might just give a hint of what went wrong

Comment: What is happing for the second row?

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: from bottom label remove bottom constraint, that is extra, if you want your label to grow with text, don't give it bottom constraint and calculate you cell's height based on label size.

Comment: Can you share code how can I set cell height based on label. Although I should not do as apple has given option to use UITableAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

Set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as `heightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension  
}
```

set `numberOfLine` of `UILabel` to **0**
& set `leading trailing top bottom constraint`